# How do I filter parent by child's EntityState value using DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would like to take an action based on when my parent class or one of its collection properties is in a state of Modified, Added, or Deleted.

```cs
public class Parent
{
    // stuff

    public IList<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    // whatever
}
```

To this end, I wrote something like this in my repository class:

```cs
// _dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();  // I toggled this on and off to see if made any difference

var modifiedParents = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Parent>()
                .Where(d => d.State == EntityState.Modified || d.State == EntityState.Added || d.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                .Select(d => d.Entity)
                .ToList();

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This works great for the Parent class, but doesn't pick up changes to the `Parent.Children` collection. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection) made it seem as though the collection changes should get picked up, but that's not the case when I only make changes to the collection. So I tried this:

```cs
var modifedParents= _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Parent>()
                    .Where(d => d.State == EntityState.Modified || d.State == EntityState.Added || d.State == EntityState.Deleted
                    || d.Collection(d => d.Children).EntityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified
                    || d.Collection(d => d.Children).EntityEntry.State == EntityState.Added
                    || d.Collection(d => d.Children).EntityEntry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                    .Select(d => d.Entity)
                    .ToList();

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This doesn't work, either. I can get things to work if, in addition to the first code sample above, I add this before the `SaveChanges()` call:

```cs
var modifiedChildren= _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Child>()
                .Where(d => d.State == EntityState.Modified || d.State == EntityState.Added || d.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                .Select(d => d.Entity)
                .ToList();
```

But it seems like I should be able to combine the two filters into one expression. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```cs
var modifedParents = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Parent>()
    .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Deleted
    || entry.Collection(parent => parent.Children)
            .CurrentValue.Any(child =>
                _dbContext.Entry(child).State == EntityState.Modified
                || _dbContext.Entry(child).State == EntityState.Added
                || _dbContext.Entry(child).State == EntityState.Deleted))
    .Select(pe => pe.Entity)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much.

Comment: Wouldn't deleted childs not exist in Collection().CurrentValue anymore?